# Using devise form inside Rails custom form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I am using Devise gem for authentication in my current project. I am stuck with an issue to use devise registration and login form inside my custom form and I am not sure how to implementation it in my project.

This custom form has 20-25 fields and if current user is not logged in, I want to include device login and registration forms as well on same view. So when user hit save button of the form, controller will first authenticate or register the user and then later save the form.

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @book = Shop::Book.new
    end

    def create
        @book = Book.new(params[:book])

        # TODO::
        # validate / register the user if not currently logged-in

        if @book.save
            redirect_to :action => 'list'
        else
            @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
            render :action => 'new'
        end   
    end
end
```

Comment: You could show both forms in one view, then use an ajax request for the login/registration form so the user doesn't need to leave the page to login.  The only other way I can think of is to set up a relationship between devise and your custom form data and use form_for.

Comment: See if this helps. http://pupeno.com/2010/08/29/show-a-devise-log-in-form-in-another-page/

Comment: I thought about making form_remote_tag for login & registration first but it has some usability issue. This form will have just one button "Save", which will login/register the user first and then proceed to save the model.

Comment: Would it work for you to use the 2 forms on the view, then create a single save submit button to submit both forms ajax style, just specify async: false in the $.ajax options so that it will finish the first request with devise first before doing your custom form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out Digi_Cazter's link then add the form after checking for signed_in?

In your create method something like this should work:

```
   @user = User.new(:email => 'test@example.com', :password => 'password',    #values from params   
   :password_confirmation => 'password')
   @user.save
   sign_in @user  #if you want to do this

       if @book.save
            redirect_to :action => 'list'
        else
            @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
            render :action => 'new'
        end
```